# I want to make call for a number in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using Sqlite Database in android and I inserted  phone number on it and gave action_call permission  for that .If I  clicked the list for making a call .The call is going for another number 
For ex; I entered the number 9944353429.but the call is going for +783743882583.

Can any one tell the solution for this please thanks in advance.

Comment: u must be fetching wrong data from db, check ur id first which is got from listview clicked

Comment: This can be also caused by ListView rows recycling. Check [this blog](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) if you set up your adapter correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have mentionend, i guess you are not retrieving the correct number from the database. Check the number being retrieved from the database before the call goes by debug.